# Google Sheets Trying to copy chart with formulas without changing the relative position

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image]

so for example i posted the chart i made to calculate shipping price from diff agents.
So all i need to do is update their price under their name and the shipping price per unit changes automatically
example formula
E5  =SUM(E$3/$D$15*$D5/$B5)

when i copy this whole chart it wont use the correct cells for the formula. the CBM total cell at the bottom will not be used if i copy the chart elsewhere.   what $ should i use and is there a better way?

Comment: Hello, I don't understand which chart you are talking about. You pasted a table. As you are new to the community please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: well im ment this table...    sorry for my bad english here. but i hope u understood what im talking about. 
If i copy this table to another sheet the formulas dont match the cells in them and i need to rewrite the formulas.  i just want the formulas to use same cells as relative to them

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, with no sensitive data, and indicate what range of cells you are copying, and where you are copying it to.  Then we can try to recreate your issue, and identify a solution.  Normally when you copy and paste a cell with a formula, the formula will update to reflect the change in relative cell location - except where you have used a "$" in the formula to "fix" that part of the range. So copying "=SUM(E$3/$D$15*$D5/$B5)" from E5 to H10 would change the formula to "=SUM(H$3/$D$15*$D10/$B10)".  We might help by trying arrayformulas, if you share your sheet.